# Rails 4 has_many through join table manage attribute increasing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following models in Rails 4 with a simple has_many :through association:

```
class Plan < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :item
  quantity: decimal
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :plans
  has_many :items, through: :plans
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :plans
  has_many :projects, through: :plans
  belongs_to :unit
end
```

I have 6 plans:

```
2.1.1 :002 > Plan.all.count
   (0.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "plans"
=> 6
```

I can't acces to quantity attribute:

```
2.1.1 :014 > Plan.where(item_id: 1, project_id: 2).count
   (0.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "plans" WHERE "plans"."item_id" = 1 AND "plans"."project_id" = 2
 => 1 
2.1.1 :015 > Plan.where(item_id: 1, project_id: 2).quantity
NoMethodError:   Plan Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "plans".* FROM "plans" WHERE "plans"."item_id" = 1 AND "plans"."project_id" = 2
undefined method `quantity' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_Plan:0x000000020a8d48>
```

When a plan contains an item and add same item one more, then have to increase quantity.

The plan controller:

```
def create
   @plan = Plan.new(plan_params)
   @plan.project_id =  @project.id
    if @project.plans.where(:item_id => @plan.item_id).blank?
      @plan.save
      redirect_to project_plans_url
    else
      **?????**
      redirect_to project_plans_url
    end
  end

private
  def set_project
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
  end

  def plan_params
    params.require(:plan).permit(:item_id, :quantity)
  end
```

How can I manage the controller **else** branch?

Comment: So `quantity` is number of records in `plans` table grouped by `item_id`?  Is it a method, or is it a column in the table?

Comment: Quantity is a decimal column in the Plan table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
@plan.project_id =  @project.id
new_plan = @project.plans.where(item_id: @plan.item_id).first_or_initialize
new_plan.quantity += 1
new_plan.save
```

and in that case you don't need else at all.

Comment: old_plan = @project.plans.where(item_id: @plan.item_id)
      
new_plan = @project.plans.where(item_id: @plan.item_id).first_or_initialize
      
new_plan.quantity += old_plan.quantity
      
new_plan.save

Throw an error: undefined method `quantity' for #<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation::ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation_Plan:0x00000002219b78>

Quantity is a decimal column in a Plan table.

Comment: Sorry missed your comment. How it finally works out?

Comment: Like your advise, I have to change only this row: new_plan.quantity += @plan.quantity. Thanks Sergey!